# Running PHPUnit from eclipse PHPUnitLogger error and a port 7478 error

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, phpunit, octobercms

I can run phpunit effortlessly from commandline, no hitches there, but I thought it might be easier if I can run it directly from eclipse. I have never set up eclipse PHPUnit before so I followed a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7hTrig3rpw) to set up PHPunit.
That one fails just as bad as the default php unit run the PDT enviroment provides.

But when I set up PHPUnit I get two errors and 0 hits on Google where to start resolving the issues.

I'm using php 7.2 TS on a windows 7 64bit system with Eclipse Oxygen.

When I try to run the tests I get the following error as a popup

> Cannot launch PHPUnit tests (port address 7478): Accept timed out

[image: error popup]

And in the console I get:

> PHPUnit 6.2.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Could not use "PHPUnitLogger" as printer.

I'm trying to run the tests under OctoberCMS, which is based upon Laravel. And as I said, the unit tests work as they should in the console.

What do I need to change to get PHPUnit working in eclipse?

Comment: thats a very styrange port you have chosen to use. Usually its port 9000, or in the case of FPM using 9000, then usually people set it to 9001

Comment: @delboy1978uk I haven't set anything up really, it's all default settings I get from eclipse. I don't even see why PHPUnit needs a port to run.

Comment: @Tschallacka Did you find a reason/solution? I am struggling same port error on newer versions such as PHPUnit 10 and 11.

Comment: @ino I started using phpstorm and have had no issues with that. So sadly no.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this question since I had the same problem with Eclipse. In case someone else finds this problem, here is my solution:

In the "plugins" folder of your Eclipse installation you can find the File PHPUnitLogger.php. On Linux you can find it with the "locate" command, but it should be something like

```
<your_eclipse_folder>/plugins/org.eclipse.php.phpunit_<some_version>/resources/printer/PHPUnitLogger.php
```

Load this file in your bootstrap.php via require_once.

Comment: I will try this later on. Will accept when it ends up working!